# A Python Decimal equivalent isclose method

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare two Decimals in Python with a tolerance of 0.01.
When using Math isclose I receive False because of floating point inaccuracy. For example:

```
d = Decimal('123.12')
d1 = Decimal('123.11')
print(isclose(d,d1,abs_tol=0.01))
```

Will print out False. 
I know the reason for this I'm just trying to understand if there is a good way to compare Decimals in Python.

Answer (score 3):

The `Decimal` class implements many methods with which you can define the comparison easily as follows:

```
abs(d - d1) <= Decimal('0.01')
```